# which software/libraries should install to do kinect programming using python language and in linux os

Tags: kinect, kinect-v2

We are doing a project on "gait analysis" in Ubuntu using skeleton tracking. Which are the libraries we will need in order to start the project . Are there any available tutorials which can help us ?

Answer (score 0):

this link should get you started [kinect with python](https://github.com/Kinect/PyKinect2)

Comment: I need the tutorial for Ubuntu. Pykinect2 is for windows.

Comment: This link might be useful [Hooking up Kinect With Ubuntu](http://www.instructables.com/id/Hooking-up-a-Kinect-to-your-Computer-Using-Ubuntu/)